# Canonical replacement for check_mem_region()

Tags: linux, driver

```
#define check_mem_region(start,n)   __check_region(&iomem_resource, (start), (n))
```

was removed from ioport.h in v4.1. I've inherited some old device driver code and need to replace this call.

Is there a canonical replacement?

PS> I'm targeting the v4.16.9 kernel.